# Concatenating a variable in the middle of an other variable

Tags: php

So I have this code; both of them echo normaly the same variable, yet only the second one will appear...

```
<?php
$i=3;
echo ${'imgmod_data_' . $i . '[\'artist\']'};
echo $imgmod_data_3['artist'];?>
```

For this first echo it gives error :

> "Notice: Undefined variable: imgmod_data_3['artist']"

So if anybody can explain why I get this error, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not have `$imgmod_data` be an array as well? So you can do `$imgmod_data[$i]['artist']` no need for evaulation.

Comment: @Halcyon Yes i could have done that, this is true .

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ${'imgmod_data_' . $i}['artist'];
```

The array dereference part should not be a string

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/bmWcuW

Comment: Ahhh yes ... thanks for such an efficient and fast answer !

Comment: No problem, glad i could help#